# Listening to 1 input event checking multiple input values

Tags: javascript

A simple question, is there a way to receive the values of multiple input fields when typing in one of those fields?

So let's say I have 3 inputs and their values are: 1, 2 and 3.

I do a forEach on all input fields and add an input eventlistener

Let's say I change the first value to 5, which gives me: 5, 2 and 3.
How do I receive all these values when changed?
I know I can use e.target.value; to receive the value from the field I typed in, but I need all values every time there is an input change.

My goal is to have a total value that keeps updating when a value changes.

How am I supposed to receive the values of ALL inputs when something is typed?

```
  const init = () => {
    $amountField.forEach($field => {
      $field.addEventListener('input', updateAmount);
    });

  const updateAmount = e => {
    console.log(e);
  };
```

Comment: would you post your code?

Comment: Give these inputs the same class, with an "onkeyup" (for example) event that once triggered will parse them all and add their values.

Comment: And how would I parse them all? what do I need to type in the function once the keyup event is triggered? I don't really know a lot about events, I know the very basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer uses [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) as well as [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

in a nutshell, we query all the inputs. Then add input [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). So every time there's an `input` event on any of the inputs we call `getTotal()`

In `getTotal()`, we create a new array made up of the input values. We then reduce that array to get the total.

```js
const inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll(".my-input")]
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;

const getTotal = () => {
  const values = inputs.map(input => Number(input.value));
  const total = values.reduce(reducer);
  console.log(total);
}

inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('input', getTotal));
```

```html
<input class="my-input first">
<input class="my-input second">
<input class="my-input third">
```

Comment: Thank you, this was a very good solution! I never think about functions like reduce and map etc. My logic is a bit chaotic.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a `class` property to each of inputs and bind a change listener to all of them.

The listener function can get to the latest values of each input by iterating on them.

```js
const inputFields = document.getElementsByClassName("ips");
let totalValue = 0;

/*get current value of each input field*/
const ipChangeListener = function() {
  totalValue = 0;
  Array.from(inputFields).forEach(function(e) {
    console.info(e.value);
    totalValue += e.value ? parseFloat(e.value) : 0;
  });
  console.info("Current Total::", totalValue);
};

/*bind a listener to change of each input field*/
Array.from(inputFields).forEach(function(e) {
  e.addEventListener("change", ipChangeListener);
});
```

```html
<form id="fields-form">
  <input id="first-ip" class="ips" type="text" name="FirstInput" value="1"><br>
  <input id="second-ip" class="ips" type="text" name="SecondInput" value="2"><br>
  <input id="third-ip" class="ips" type="text" name="ThirdInput" value="3"><br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution

```js
const myFunc = function() {
//update result after callstack is empty
setTimeout(() => {
    let result = 0
    for (let input of document.getElementsByName("myInput")) {
        result += input.value - 0 //convert to number
    }
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result
}, 0)
}
```

```html
<input class="first" name="myInput" type="number" onkeydown="myFunc()">
<input class="second" name="myInput" type="number" onkeydown="myFunc()">
<input class="third" name="myInput" type="number" onkeydown="myFunc()">
<div id="result"></div>
```